# Multiply Column with one cell value and sum it

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to multiply each value of  a column range (e.g., A1:A10) by another cell value and then sum them up. When I try sumproduct, it gives me an error.

Effectively I am trying to do this - SUMPRODUCT(B1,A1:A10)

Comment: Please expand your question to show the formula you tried and the error.

Comment: Try `=SUM(A1:A10)*B1`

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication is distributive so:

```
ax + ay + az = a(x + y + z)
```

As an Excel formula that would be:

```
=SUM(A1:A10) * B1
```

Comment: Well put. I forgot about this. Thank you for helping me revisit basic mathematics :)!